# How to remember keyboard state when navigating from certain view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uikeyboard

I have a chat view controller that I automatically open the keyboard with (upon opening the page) on making the textview as a first responder. In my chat view, however, users can navigate away from the page to view the profile of the user they are chatting with. How can I alter the keyboard state depending on the user's behavior?

1) If users click on a message thread it will always automatically open the keyboard.

2) While in chat, if users click on the user's picture to view their profile, it will remember the state of the keyboard when they come back to the chat. If they had dismissed the keyboard, it will not load the keyboard, if it was still up, it will load the keyboard.

Would love some help here! Thanks. You guys are the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is closely related to 'Design' aspect of your application.

I am assuming that your application has a single `UINavigationController` which keeps a stack of all your `UIViewController` instances.
Also, I am assuming that when a user navigates away from `ChatViewController` screen,  you are pushing new screen over the current `ChatViewController` instance and not popping the `ChatViewController` instance and then pushing over it.

Considering above 2 assumptions, there are many ways to accomplish what you want.

**Quick Way:**

Declare a `boolean` variable `isChatInProgress` in your `ChatViewController` class and assign it value `true` or `false`, depending upon whether the chat is in progress or not.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if isChatInProgress {
        chatTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**Better Approach**

Rather than just declaring a `boolean` variable `isChatInProgress`, you can make your code more Object Oriented and scalable by declaring a model class `ChatState` (subclass of `NSObject` in case of Objective C).

```
class ChatState {

    var isChatInProgress : Bool
    var chatText : String
    var chatId: String
    .
    .
}
```

You can include all variables that might be helpful in defining state of your chat screen inside your `ChatState` class. Then, In the `viewDidLoad` method of your class just initialize an instance of `ChatViewController` like so :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.chatState = ChatState(param1, param2, ...)
}

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if self.chatState.isChatInProgress {
        chatTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Once you have initialized instance of `ChatViewController`, you can keep updating its parameters depending upon the event. For e.g. when a user starts a chat with other user, you can set the `isChatInProgress` variable of `chatState` to `true`.

One added advantage of this approach is that it will also be helpful in case you want to persist your chat state between various session of your application. You can archive `ChatState` objects in any data store (NSUserDefaults, CoreData, Sqlite) of your choosing and retrieve them later on.

Comment: AMAZING RESPONSE!! Thank you so much :) This is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

on the view controller that you want the keyboard to automatically open you want this function in there

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

  yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()



}
```

then to keep the text that is there you can just save the value in a global variable and stick it back in to the value that you want on the return back to the controller

and if you want to remember the state you can use userdefaults and set a flag thats checks is the keyboard is dismissed or not, and use conditional logic based upon that flag